# c++ multiple lambdas in struct?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, auto

Say I have a struct:

```
struct func{
    std::string symbol;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<double (double, double)> operate;
    std::function<complex (double, double)> operate2;
};
```

I want some `func` objects to use a lambda that returns `double` type, while I want others to use a lambda that returns `complex` type. Is this a viable/efficient way of doing that? My only concern is that in the construction of objects of type `func`, I'll have to list an implementation of each lambda, even when I only want one. This is unnecessary work for the compiler and unnecessary storage in memory.

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps with generic types? I could not seem to get this working with template T or auto.

Comment: `virtual` functions and inheritance?

Comment: you could make the function return a `variant<double,complex>`.

Comment: @JeJo only one at a time, which is why I feel like having both declarations is inefficient.

Comment: Do you want to be able to have a bunch of `func` objects in some sort of container, like a `vector` or `array`?

Comment: @Raildex would a valid lambda be `std::function<variant<double, complex> (double, double)> operate;` then? And in each instantiation of a `func` object I could return either a `complex` type or a `double` type?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, I'm storing all my `func` objects as values in an unordered map (std::string func_name -> func function_operation). So from a string I can find the corresponding function and perform the operation using the lambda

Comment: Not actually relevant to the question but just terminology. `std::function` does not mean "lambda". "Lambda expression" is the name for the syntax `[]() { }`. A lambda expression creates a functor object, where a functor is a certain kind/pattern of class. A `std::function` is a different object that *can* store the functor object made by a lambda expression *but* can also be a bunch of other things. This question is not about "lambdas", it is about "functions"/`std::function`s. Ranting aside, yes, use `variant`, but no, not like that. `std::variant<std::function<...>, std::function<...>>`.

Comment: @HTNW thanks for the clarification! could you elaborate on why the variant cant be used inside std::function to interchange the return type?

Comment: @rjc810 It *can*, it'll just mean something different. When `std::function<std::variant<double, complex>(double, double)> func` then e.g. `func(0, 0)` can return `double` while `func(0, 1)` returns `complex`. The choice of return type may vary with the arguments. For `std::variant<std::function<double(double, double)>, std::function<complex(double, double)>> func`, you *first* inspect `func` to find which branch it's on and then you know whether it returns `complex` or `double` for *all* arguments. Which one do you want?

Comment: Suppose you have a `func` object and you invoke its stored operation. How do you know what type the returned value is?